# update trigger of cron job

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, crontrigger

I have a cron job which has multiple triggers all triggers have been scheduled for the interval of lets say 5 min, now I need to update job data map at runtime, for that I need that particular trigger which requires to update but I am failing to get that particular trigger, I am doing something like that

```
String cronExpression = "0 0/5 * * * ?"
String triggername = "mytrigger" + System.currentTimeMillis()
JobDataMap jobDataMap = new JobDataMap([host: config.host, port: config.port, username: config.username, password: config.password])
CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
        .withIdentity(triggername)
        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpression)).usingJobData(jobDataMap)
        .build()
MyJob.schedule(trigger)
```

Any idea how can I get that particular trigger which I have to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved the trigger name in database, and when I need to update that trigger I simply fetch that trigger like this:

```
TriggerKey triggerKey = new TriggerKey(triggerName_from_db);
try {
    Trigger trigger = quartzScheduler.getTrigger(triggerKey)
    if (trigger?.key?.name) {
        trigger.jobDataMap['host'] = config.host
        trigger.jobDataMap['port'] = config.port
        trigger.jobDataMap['username'] = config.username
        trigger.jobDataMap['password'] = config.password
    }
    quartzScheduler.rescheduleJob(triggerKey, trigger)
    }catch (SchedulerException ex) {
    log.error ex.toString()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
List<Trigger> triggers = quartzScheduler.jobGroupNames.collect {
    quartzScheduler.getJobKeys(GroupMatcher.groupEquals(it)).collect {
        quartzScheduler.getTriggersOfJob(it)
    }
}.flatten()
```

It will return all your scheduled triggers. After get them you can do what you need in JobDataMap.

I suggest use a familiar trigger identity, it make easier to find a specific one at runtime.